# Delete a project on local PC and get again from TFS to another folder

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

In VisualStudio 2013, I downloaded a project from TFS. But I saved it in wrong folder.

I wanna delete this folder and get it again from TFS to the right place. But Source Control Explorer says it's already available.

How can I move the project on local HD?

Comment: In the Source Control Explorer I think you can right click on the project folder and change the mapping locally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change or remove the workspace mapping, Go to File -> Source Control -> Advanced -> Workspaces -> Select the workspace name in the 'manage Workspaces' -> Edit. Change the Local Folder the path.

If you want to remove, use remove button instead edit.